# How to find the number of rows in data frame that are almost duplicates i.e. differ by less than two entries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with that looks something like:

```
     | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7
row1 |  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |  e   |  f   |  g
row2 |  a   |  a   |  c   |  d   |  e   |  f   |  g   
row3 |  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |  a   |  a   |  g   
row4 |  a   |  q   |  q   |  q   |  q   |  q   |  q
```

I'd like to calculate the number of rows that are the same as another row except for fewer than two entries and put them in a column/series.

So in this case row 2 and 3 are similar to 1. Therefore the entry for row 1 would be 2. The overall result would be:

```
     | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7  | almost_dups
row1 |  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |  e   |  f   |  g    |  2
row2 |  a   |  a   |  c   |  d   |  e   |  f   |  g    |  1
row3 |  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |  e   |  a   |  a    |  1 
row4 |  a   |  q   |  q   |  q   |  q   |  q   |  q    |  0
```

My initial thought is to define a distance metric between rows.

Comment: Why is the `almost_dups` values for `row2` and `row3` are different from the one for `row1`? They each have the same number of "siblings".

Comment: @ayorgo Sorry my mistake - I edited row 3 but forgot to change the first example. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this code. A quick solution by a beginner here, but I think it works OK.

```
import pandas as pd
# let's create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ['a','a','a','a'], 
                          'col2': ['b','a','b','q'],
                          'col3': ['c','c','c','q'],
                          'col4': ['d','d','d','q'], 
                          'col5': ['e','e','a','q'],
                          'col6': ['f','f','a','q'],
                          'col7': ['g','g','g','q']} )

almost_dups = []            # initialize the list we want to compute    
for i in range(len(df)):    # for every dataframe row
    a = df.iloc[i].values   # get row values
    count = 0               # this will count the rows similar to the selected one 
    for j in range(len(df)): # for every other row
        if i!=j:            # if rows are different
            b = df.iloc[j].values
            if sum([i == j for i, j in zip(a, b)])>= 5: # if at least 5 values are same
                count +=1   # increase counter
    almost_dups.append(count) # append the count
df['almost_dups'] = almost_dups   # append the list to dataframe, as a new column
```

Comment: Thank you. Please consider optimizing if you want to apply to large dataframes. You can avoid repeating comparisons, meaning that you can compare proximity of rows (i,j) and (j,i) only once (while the above code computes it twice)

Comment: The question is not asked by me..OP can consider the same

Answer (score 1):

that would work (not sure if that's optimized though)

```
cols = df.columns
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
df_result['index'] = df['index']
df_result['result'] = 0
for index_ln, row_ln in df.iterrows():
    count_same = 0
    for index_col, row_col in df.iterrows():        
        count=0
        for col in cols:
            if row_ln[col] != row_col[col]:
                count+=1
        if count<=2:
            count_same+=1        
    df_result['result'] = np.where(df_result['index']==row_ln['index'], count_same-1, df_result['result'])
    print(count_same)
df = df.merge(df_result, on='index')
```